# Custom confirmbox, wait for button click in function Javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to make a confirmbox that returns true or false. If the user clicks OK it has to return true and if the user clicks Cancel or the cross in the upperleft corner it has to return false. But I'm stuck at the point the user clicks the button. I've already tried using callbacks but it could not help me to achieve what I would like to have.

So far I have this:

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/MarkkNijboer/BW463/)

```
function SimpleAlert( title, text, cancel)
{
    var stylesheet = document.createElement('style');
    stylesheet.id="SimpleAlertStylesheet";
    stylesheet.innerHTML="#SimpleAlertOverlay { top:0px; bottom:0px; left:0px; right:0px; position:fixed; background:rgba(230,230,230,0.5); height:100%; width:100%; font-family:Sans-serif; } #SimpleAlertLightbox { background:#f5f5f5; border-radius:3px; width:400px; box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); } .SimpleAlertTopbar { border-radius:3px; background:#e5e5e5; height:24px; color:#444; line-height:24px; padding:0px 5px; font-weight:bold; font-size:14px; border-bottom:1px solid #DDD } .SimpleAlertCross1 { margin:5px 15px 0px 0px; opacity:0.7; } .SimpleAlertCross2 { margin:5px 15px 0px 0px; opacity:0.5; } .SimpleAlertCross1:hover { opacity:1; } .SimpleAlertTopbar > div { float:left } .SimpleAlertMessagediv { padding:20px 40px; font-size:14px; color:#444; } .SimpleAlertButtondiv { height:26px; line-height:26px; padding:0px 40px 18px 40px; } .SimpleAlertButtondiv button { height:26px; background:#f9f9f9; border:1px solid #CCC; color:#444; float:right; } .SimpleAlertButtondiv button:hover { border:1px solid #AAA; } .SimpleAlertButtondiv button:focus { outline:none; }";

    var overlay = document.createElement('div');
    overlay.id = 'SimpleAlertOverlay';
    var lightbox = document.createElement('div');
    lightbox.id = 'SimpleAlertLightbox';
    overlay.appendChild(lightbox);
    var topbar = document.createElement('div');
    topbar.setAttribute("class", "SimpleAlertTopbar");
    lightbox.appendChild(topbar);
    var crossdiv = document.createElement('div');
    topbar.appendChild(crossdiv);
    var crossspan = document.createElement('span');
    crossdiv.appendChild(crossspan);
    var cross = document.createElement('img');

    if(cancel)
    {
        cross.setAttribute("class", "SimpleAlertCross1");
    }
    else
    {
        cross.setAttribute("class", "SimpleAlertCross2");
    }

    cross.src = 'data:image/png;base64,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';
    crossspan.appendChild(cross);
    var titlediv = document.createElement('div');
    titlediv.innerHTML = title;
    topbar.appendChild(titlediv);
    var messagediv = document.createElement('div');
    messagediv.setAttribute("class", "SimpleAlertMessagediv");
    messagediv.innerHTML = text;
    lightbox.appendChild(messagediv);
    var buttondiv = document.createElement('div');
    buttondiv.setAttribute("class", "SimpleAlertButtondiv");
    lightbox.appendChild(buttondiv);
    var okbutton = document.createElement('button');
    okbutton.innerHTML="OK";
    buttondiv.appendChild(okbutton);
    document.body.appendChild(overlay);
    document.body.appendChild(stylesheet);

    Element.prototype.remove = function() {
        this.parentElement.removeChild(this);
    }

    function CenterDiv(elementId){
         var main = document.getElementById(elementId);
         var wi=main.offsetWidth;
         var he=main.offsetHeight;
         var marginleft = wi / 2;
         var margintop = he / 2;
         main.style.marginLeft="-" + marginleft;
         main.style.marginTop="-" + margintop;
         main.style.position="absolute";
         main.style.left="50%";
         main.style.top="50%"
        }
        CenterDiv('SimpleAlertLightbox');

        if(cancel)
        {
            var cancelbutton = document.createElement('button');
            cancelbutton.innerHTML="Cancel";
            cancelbutton.style.marginRight="30px";
            buttondiv.appendChild(cancelbutton);
            cancelbutton.addEventListener('click', SimpleAlertCancel , false);
        }
        cross.addEventListener('click', SimpleAlertCancel , false);
        okbutton.addEventListener('click', SimpleAlertOK , false);

        function SimpleAlertCancel()
        {
            document.body.removeChild(document.getElementById('SimpleAlertOverlay'));
            document.body.removeChild(document.getElementById('SimpleAlertStylesheet'));
        }
        function SimpleAlertOK()
        {
            document.body.removeChild(document.getElementById('SimpleAlertOverlay'));
            document.body.removeChild(document.getElementById('SimpleAlertStylesheet'));
        }
}
```

What I'm trying to achieve is:

```
if(SimpleAlert('title', 'text', true))
{
  //User clicked OK
}
else
{
  //User clicked Cancel
}
```

I am looking for something like the system functions: alert(), confirm() and prompt(). These functions pause all Javascript and wait until a button has been clicked.

I have browsed throught all the folders of the internet browsers installed on my computer to find the above functions declared but i couldn't find them.

Here is an image of the alertbox for the person that doesn't open the fiddle ;-)

[image]

I hope you can help me to get a step closer.

Comment: What's wrong with `confirm`?

Comment: @SomeKittensUx2666 Confirm works great but i would like to make a custom confirmbox. I would like to make a custom one because the appearance of the embedded confirmbox differs for every browser.

Comment: You're going to have to use callbacks - there's no way to halt JS execution in the same way that ```alert```, ```prompt``` and ```confirm``` do.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that with Javascript, as it is asynchronous, the code continues executing even if the window/div is shown.

For managing the actions, execute the code you need on the **onclick** events on each of the "OK" and "Cancel" buttons